# simple tar and extract command

Tags: command-line, backup, tar, extract

I am new to Ubuntu (terminal especially) and I am experimenting with the `tar` command.

I have created a `/test` folder containing one single `/test.txt` file at `/var/www/html/test/test.txt`.

I would like to tar **only the `/test` folder** (and its contents) to `/home/jo/backup`.

My process so far is as follows:

```
cd ~ 
tar cvf testBackup.tar /var/www/html/test/
```

This successfully creates a `testBackup.tar` located at `/home/jo/backup`. 
However when I extract the tar using the following command:

```
tar cvf testBackup.tar /var/www/html/test/
```

The folder `var` is visible, and I have to cd to the `/test` directory (/var/www/html/test) in order to see the contents.

Basically I only want to tar the `test` folder, not the three before (`/var/www/html`)

Am I doing something wrong or is this how the command works?

Comment: use `cd /var/www/html/;tar cvf testBackup.tar ./test;mv testBackup.tar ~/backup/`

Comment: thanks @LittleByBlue can you briefly explain what this is doing? Or what I am doing wrong? :)

Comment: you need to go to the directory above `test`. see also: `man tar` I'll make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tar is designed for backups,too

you may specify the least distant path. In your case it is `test`.

So you can use this chain:

```
cd /var/www/html;tar cvf testBackup.tar ./test;mv testBackup.tar ~/backup/


cd /var/www/html;tar cvf testBackup.tar ./test;rsync  testBackup.tar ~/backup/;rm testBackup.tar # for cross net compability
```

which will `tar` only your  `test` folder and move it to your backup directory.

**See also**:

```
man tar
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Why do you use the `mv` command? You could specify the correct target directly...

Comment: @ByteCommander as it is more extensible (eg using `rsync`)

Answer (score 4):

go to the location and run the command

```
cd /var/www/html
tar cvf /home/jo/backup/testBackup.tar test
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically I go to the directory first, then execute the tar command.  This way, we do the dancing up front and allow easy what-you-want extract in the end:

```
cd /var/www/html
tar cvf ~/testBackup.tar test
```

The tar command probably has options that allow the same thing without the dancing, just read the man page (`man tar`).